# NSData to NSString with JSON response

Tags: ios, json, encoding, nsstring, nsdata

**NSData* jsonData** is the http response contains JSON data.

```
NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"jsonString: %@", jsonString);
```

I got the result:

```
{ "result": "\u8aaa" }
```

What is the proper way to encoding the data to the correct string, not unicode string like "\uxxxx"?

Comment: Did u try NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData]; ?

Comment: How exactly did you print `{ "result" = "\U8aaa"; }` ? That looks (almost) like the NSLog of a dictionary. Do you already use a JSON parser (e.g. NSJSONSerialization) ?

Comment: This is tough because it should be \u not \U.  Is there anything you can do about that?

Comment: @MartinR: I used AFNetworking to request. And then get the responseData. Not yet use a JSON parser. I tried JSONKit to parse but it also get the same result.

Comment: @borrrden: Yes, you are right. It is lowercase 'u'. I edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: @shiami: Is that really the output of `jsonString`? I just wonder because JSON would look like `{ "result" : "\u8aaa" }`.

Comment: @shiami: Perhaps you can show more code, starting with the AFNetworking request.

Comment: @MartinR: Yes, I just printed with dictionary. Now I edited to the correct string.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you convert the JSON data

```
{ "result" : "\u8aaa" }
```

to a `NSDictionary` (e.g. using `NSJSONSerialization`) and print the dictionary

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", jsonDict);
```

then you will get the output

```
{
    result = "\U8aaa";
}
```

The reason is that the `description` method of `NSDictionary` uses "\Unnnn" escape sequences
for all non-ASCII characters. But that is only for *display* in the console, the dictionary is *correct*!

If you print the value of the key

```
NSLog(@"%@", [jsonDict objectForKey:@"result"]);
```

then you will get the expected output

```
說
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right about it. Now I finally figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what the problem is. AFNetworking has given you a valid JSON packet. If you want the above code to output the character instead of the `\u…` escape sequence, you should coax the server feeding you the result to change its output. But this shouldn't be necessary. What you most likely want to do next is run it through a JSON deserializer…

```
NSDictionary * data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData …];
```

…and you should get the following dictionary back: `@{@"result":@"說"}`. Note that the `result` key holds a string with a single character, which I'm guessing is what you want.

BTW: In future, I suggest you copy-paste output into your question rather than transcribing it by hand. It'll avoid several needless rounds of corrections and confusion.