# How to NSLog NSData JSON response in JSON format?

Tags: objective-c, json, nsstring, nsdata, nslog

Is there a way I can `NSLog` `JSON` response of `NSData` in `JSON`format?

```
NSLog(@"JSON NSString: %@" ,jsonData);
```

[In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337782/nsdata-to-nsstring-with-json-response) they are printing `NSDictionary`,I can convert it to NSDictionary. and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467844/convert-utf-8-encoded-nsdata-to-nsstring) solution returns `(null)`.

How can I `NSLog` in JSON format?

Comment: What's your code to convert that `jsonData` exactly?

Comment: @Lamre jsonData is NSData. I need code to print it. I can convert it to NSDictionary but it can't be compared in codebeautify.

Comment: are you confirm your NSData not nil.

Comment: @balkaransingh yes

Comment: @ShuvoJoseph check my answer.

Comment: if you've successfully converted the NSData to NSDictionary than there should be no problem in printing the dictionary try checking the error and try to access object at index or object for keys to check if they exist.

Comment: @dreamBegin I can print the dictionary but can't use the data in codebeautify.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert UTF-8 encoded NSData to NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467844/convert-utf-8-encoded-nsdata-to-nsstring)

Comment: @Desdenova it is mentioned in the question!

Comment: @ShuvoJoseph: You need to understand a thing or two. If you transform the NSData into a NSDictionary with NSJSONSerialization, and you print it, it will use the description method of NSDictionary. Not a "JSON" stuff. You need to use `initWithData:encoding:`

Comment: @Larme I tried different encoding.

Comment: If there is no "private" info in the JSON, can you give us the `NSData` object?

Comment: @Larme I tried to comment here, but it's too big. Is there a way I can send you the NSData and NSDictionary?

Comment: You can edit the question with it, or use pastern or other similar services.

Comment: How did you get `jsonDictionary`? I tried some stuff from `jsonData`, and it seems that you use `NSKeyedArchiver`, trying to save the `NSDictionary` and not the JSON.

Comment: NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

Comment: It shouldn't, since with the `jsonData` you gave, I can't have your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

• What's wrong:
**`jsonData` (as you gave) IS NOT a hexData representing a JSON.**

• Quick **hack** (not viable solution!) to get your JSON to use in your site CodeBeautify:

```
NSDictionary *dictFromData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:jsonData];
NSData *realJSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictFromData options:0 error:nil];
NSString *strFINAL = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:realJSONData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"StrFINAL: %@", strFINAL);
```

Note: Yeah, I bypassed the `error` parameters, and we shouldn't.  With 
`NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted` instead of `0` in `options:` parameter, you have a result almost similar to the one of CodeBeautify.

• How did I get there:
Firt, I copy/paste your bump string of `NSData` with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317860/converting-hex-nsstring-to-nsdata).
That way, I got `jsonData` as you got.
Then, I tried simply what it should be given your informations:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&errorJSON];
```

Which didn't work giving the error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.)
>   UserInfo=0x17598540 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character
>   0.}

But with `NSDictionary *dictWithData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:jsonData];`, I managed to get the real `NSDictionary`. But `NSKeyedArchiver`/`NSKeyedUnarchiver` are doing something "equivalent" to `NSJSONSerialization`: it serializes, transforming a `NSObject` into `NSData` (and vice-versa). But more powerful: for any kind of object that are `NSCoding` compliant. Here, since it's originally from a JSON (only `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` objects, and not a custom one), it's working without any more code.
Did you for instance tried to save it into `NSUserDefaults` and it's not a .plist either (that was also one on my tries, I saved `jsonData` into memory, and used `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:` giving me weird answer, but a important one in the bump of it: ""$class" = "{value = 23}";" which lead me to `NSKeyArchiver`/`NSKeyUnarchiver`). I don't know what you did exactly.

• Conclusion:
*So clearly, somewhere, you mixed stuff found on the web. You need to rework that. You can't let it like this. There is issue in your code elsewhere. Where did you get `jsonData` from? What did you do with it?*

Comment: I don't have the source code right now. I can try this when I get back to office on Sunday. The data is coming from .Net server. You are guru.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
NSLog("Formatted JSON : %@" ,[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different situations. If parsing the JSON data was fine, then you just want to log the result (dictionary or array). If parsing the JSON data failed, and you suspect there is something wrong with the JSON data, then you convert the JSON data to an NSString and log that. And finally, if either conversion to NSString failed, or you look at the NSString and can't find what's wrong with it, then you log the NSData itself to be able to see the bytes. That's useful if someone managed to put control characters or some other nonsense into your JSON data.

The best is to write a method (warning! not for the timid! requires writing code yourself) that takes the NSData, analyses it and prints out the information that you need.

Comment: The issue is that the author is mixing too much stuff. For instance, with `jsonData` you can't retrieve "JSON" (as normally in 99,9% cases), but with `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:jsonData]` you can. But he/she used `NSCoding` somewhere.